# C++ #include statement

Tags: c++, eclipse, cascade

I am a Java developer and C++ beginner. In Java, I can import objects easily using (Ctrl + Shift + O). In C++ however, I have to manually type `#include` each time, wasting my time. In addition, I often don't know where the required object is.

Is there an easy way to import or type "#include" automatically? If not, is there a plug-in or add-on to do that? I am using Eclipse IDE for Blackberry 10, along with C++ Cascades.

Comment: This is just how C++ works. And if you believe it is wasting time, it is time to move back to java.

Comment: It took me 3 seconds to type #include 'file.h'

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+O is incredibly handy, but at the same time, I fear it engenders a certain sloppiness in development, or rather a certain level of disregard for what components make up your application.

Comment: @jordi12100 I don't mean #include header file, I mean other c++ and cascades libraries

Comment: I suspect the bigger issue is not the typing time, but the effort of finding the actual file to include. This is nontrivial for large C++ libraries.

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + O` is *not* a java language construct.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker - But it is an Eclipse function, the environment that he's using.

Comment: I use the "go to definition" feature of Visual Assist X (Visual Studio add-in) to find out which header file defines a cretain class. With VAX it's as easy as typing a variable declaration, placing the cursor in the class-name and pressing Alt+G => VAX opens up the header and jumps to the class definition. (I'm not sure if VAX *wants* to find definitions for stuff that isn't yet available in the current file, because an include is missing, but it does, and I'm very glad it does). -- Maybe there is some C++ refactoring tool that has a similar "go to definition" feature for Eclipse as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is just how C++ works. The `#include` functionality is primitive compared to a Java `import`: each `#include` is simply replaced by the text of the included file (and so on, recursively) as if it had been copied and pasted in there.

This sometimes has advantages, and it's certainly simple, but it does mean that there's no reliable way to know ahead of time what is defined by a particular included file. So, if you need the `vector` type, for example, that is in `vector`; but if you need the `va_list` type, that is in `stdarg.h`. Generally, things are reasonably consistent, but not perfectly so, and there's nothing to enforce it anyway. This is probably why most IDEs don't provide much help for it. You just need to know what the rules are (if there are any) for the libraries you're using.

IDE support for C++ is generally not as good as it is for Java or C#. This is one example (there are plenty of other ones). If you are expecting a Java or C#-level of assistance, you are likely to end up disappointed. On the plus side, while sorting out the `#include` list is annoying, there are lots of other difficulties encountered when working with C++, so it rarely ends up the main problem.

Answer (score 2):

see [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=45203).

It seems that people have been discussing this for about 10 years but it's not implemented yet.

Personally I believe as a C++ programmer you should be trying to eliminate excessive use of include's in your files and use **forward declarations** instead therefore it's not a feature many programmers are looking for. If you prefer not to have that much control over the program, you can always code in `java` or `c#`.

Comment: If you're using library code, you `#include` the relevant headers. You don't forward-declare the classes or functions therein, as that wouldn't be sensible.

Comment: many libraries I use have a master include file that includes all header files in the library which is quite easy to add anyways.